# C memory allocation(malloc)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *p, n, i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter element %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\n %d", p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do we need to write `&` in the scanf, if it's an array it's not necessary?
`p` is a pointer to all the memory spaces so `&p[i]` should give the address of the pointer but not where we want to store the data right?
Also if we write `*p[i]` in `printf`, it gives an error, `p` is a pointer so we should deference it and store the data in the reserved space in the memory but it's not working? Even if I compile the above program as it is it stops working after taking 3 values as input.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/296974).

Comment: What is the exact input you are giving the program? What is the exact results you are getting?

Comment: "`p` is a pointer so we should deference it": We do so, by using `p[i]` which is the same as `*(p + i)`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no. of elements:5
I could enter ele 1,ele 2 and ele 3 but then it displayed program not working and it stopped.

Comment: @glglgl
if p is a pointer then &p[0] should give the address of the pointer which is pointing the element[0] and not the memory address of element[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscript operator [] also performs dereferencing. It performs indexing and dereferencing at once. `p[n]` is equivalent to `*(p+n)`, i.e. it goes to an offset and dereferences it. Consequently, `&p[n]` is equivalent to `p+n`.

Comment: It's the subscript operator, not the dereferencing operator. (There isn't anything called the "dereferencing operator" either, although the unary * operator *does* dereference a pointer.)

Comment: Thanks for the official term. I made a little edit to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @Peter Schneider
If p[n] is equivalent to *(p+n) then why is it showing an error if we write *p[i].
Also what do u mean by &p[n] is equivalent to p+n ?

Comment: Well, `*p[i]` is as wrong as `**(p+i)`. As others say, you are trying to dereference something which is not an address (`p[i]` is a normal int, like `i`). AND: What I mean with "&p[n] is equivalent to p+n" is exactly that. The two expressions are equivalent. Perhaps it helps when I say that `p+n` is the **address** of the nth element after the element at p? And since `p[n]` is the nth element, `&p[n]` is logically the nth element's address as well.

Comment: @PeterSchneider int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5}
Now if we do int *p=arr;
Then p[i] and arr[i] are basically same right?
Now here we created a memory space and the pointer points to the memory space so we can use either p[i] or arr[i] for accessing an element, is that what we are saying?
Now say we want the pointer address then what should we write in printf?

Comment: All you say is right. "Now say we want the pointer address": Do you really want the pointer *address?* Probably you want the pointer *value*. The pointer p is a normal variable which contains a normal value, much like an int. On common platforms that value would be 4 or 8 bytes long. No magic there, just a bit pattern. You could intepret it as an int and e.g. print the number. What that number *means* is interesting: The number is the "address" of a memory location. That is what scanf needs: The address of a memory location. To change arr's first element, 1, just write `scanf("%d", p)`.

Comment: Oh, and that would be equivalent to `scanf("%d", arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

If the value is `p[i]`

```
p[i] = *(p+i)
```

Then the location should be

```
&p[i]
```

So you need to specify what is the location to which you need to store this value and it will be `&p[i]`

or `(p+i)`

```
&p[i] = (p+i)
```

Comment: don't overcomplicate things: `&p[i] == &*(p+i) == (p+i)`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I have put it in another way !! I think nothing is complicated here

Comment: you just added a mistake: `&(p+i)` is not the same as `(p+i)`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Oops yes fixed it

Comment: @Gopi When we dynamically allocate memory using malloc do we create an array with a certain no. of reserved space or a pointer which points to a reserved space?
If it's a pointer, we find the address of the pointer using &p?

Comment: @Rooney10 You will be having pointer to the first location of the memory which was allocated by `malloc()` in this case let's say that is `p` then `p+` will be the next block in that allocated memory chunk.You need a double pointer to store the address of the pointer

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need to write & in the scanf, if it's an array it's not
>   necessary?

Arrays decay to a pointer of the first element. Generally an expression `a`, where `a` is an array, turns into `&a[0]`.

> Also if we write *p[i] in printf, it gives an error, p is a pointer so
>   we should deference it and store the data in the reserved space in the
>   memory but it's not working?

No, you're trying to apply the unary * operator to something which isn't a pointer type. An expression of the form `E1[E2]` is equivalent to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`, so if whatever is yielded by * isn't a pointer type, then the syntax is invalid.

Comment: 1. P is pointer to array so &p should display the pointer address and not the memory address of the element?
2.Say int *p=&a;
a=5;
*p=8
printf("%d",*p);
It should print 8 right but 8 is not a pointer but it still shows the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `&n` to tell `scanf` where to put the data. `&` is the address operator, it returns the memory address where the variable is stored.

`&p[i]` will give the address of the `i`th element of the array.

Comment: It is not a reference operator. There are no references in C. It isn't called the reference operator in C++ either.